# snmptrap not executed, just return version

Tags: snmp, snmpd

I'm having trouble receiving the traps on my destination computer.

On the destination machine I have a `snmptrapd` server running normally.

He executed the following command in a linux that would be in charge of sending the traps.

```
snmptrapd -v1 -c public 172.31.252.200 .1.3.777 172.31.253.60 6 .0 0 .1.3.777.1 i 3 .1.3.777.2 i 8210 .1.3.777.3 i 2 .1.3.777.4 i 72 .1.3.777.5 s "TEST"
```

But it only returns the following:

> ```
>  root @ Machine1: / etc / snmp # snmptrapd -v1 -c public 172.31.252.200
>  .1.3.777 172.31.253.60 6 .0 0 .1.3.777.1 i 3 .1.3.777.2 i 8210
>  .1.3.777.3 i 2 .1.3. 777.4 i 72 .1.3.777.5 s "TEST"
>  NET-SNMP Version: 5.7.3
>  Web: http://www.net-snmp.org/
>  Email: net-snmp-coders@lists.sourceforge.net
>
>  root @ Machine1: / etc / snmp #
> ```

The command, the OID's and other data are correct. What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter `-v` is not doing what you think it would do:

From the manual:

```
-v, --version
  Print version information for the trap daemon and then exit.
```

I don't know what you want to set to `1`, but it's a different parameter.

The parameter `-c` does not exist either for snmptrapd. Both parameters exist for `snmptrap` though (notice the missing `d`).

Looks like you are trying to run `snmptrapd` with parameters intended for `snmptrap`.

Comment: Yep, its true, now the comand execute, but dont arrive to destination address.

Comment: Well, that's a different problem for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The command `snmptrap` was linked to `snmptrapd` so the parameters `-v1` and `-c public` doesnt works properly.

Making a new symbolic link works fine.